# how to solve this using Arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to programming is there a way to solve this:

> Take 10 integer inputs from user and print the following
>
> 1. number of positive numbers.
> 2. number of negative numbers.
> 3. number of odd numbers.
> 4. number of even numbers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numArray[10];

    cout<<"Enter Number :";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cin>>numArray[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numArray[i]; i++)
    {
        if(numArray[i]>0)
        {
            cout<<"Positive Number "<<numArray[i] <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Negative Number "<<numArray[i]<<endl;
        }

        if(numArray[i]%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"Odd number "<<numArray[i]<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"even number "<<numArray[i]<<endl;  
        }
    
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Hint: create integer counters that get incremented each time you see something that satisfies their criteria.

Comment: Follow @Meowmere 's advice and you'll find that you don't need the array at all.

Comment: What do you think this does? `i < numArray[i]`?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<numArray[i]; i++)` should be `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)`.

Comment: Do you want to store positive numbers, negative number odds and evens in separate arrays? Good question above why do you need arrays?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this without arrays but I'm just gonna stick with your original intent for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 10> numArray; //an array of ints, size 10. this is CPP style array, it is 'safer' than C-style array. (someone correct me)

    //get your 10 inputs.
    cout << "Enter Number :";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cin >> numArray[i];
    }

    int positive_count = 0;
    int negative_count = 0;
    int even_count = 0;
    int odd_count = 0;
    
    //loop thru your 10 inputs, increment counters accordingly.
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numArray.size(); i++)
    {
        
        if (numArray[i] < 0)
        {
            negative_count += 1;
        }
        if (numArray[i] > 0)
        {
            positive_count += 1;
        }

        if (numArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            even_count += 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            odd_count += 1;
        }
    
    }
    
    cout << "Positive Number " << positive_count << endl;
    cout << "Negative Number " << negative_count << endl;
    
    cout << "even number " << even_count << endl;  
    cout << "Odd number " << odd_count << endl;
    
    return 0;
   
}
```

Comment: Is `0` positive nubmer?

Comment: what is the difference between #include <array> and just creating an array inside the main method?

Comment: #include is a preprocessor directive. It tells your compiler that 'hey I want the library called array'. If you just create an array without #include<array>, you will get compile error as the machine has no clue what is this name 'array', or where it can be found.

Comment: Alexis besides my point of `0` above. I would suggest merging input loop and count loop.

Comment: @KPCT 0 is neither positive nor negative. If you ask non-negative integers, 0 is included. If you want non-positive integers, 0 is included too. But, 0 is neither positive nor negative. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative#:~:text=Actually%2C%20zero%20is%20neither%20a,that%20are%20bigger%20than%20zero.

Comment: Don't include 0 into the positive count. Neither into negative count.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in input loop:

```
int positives = 0, zeros = 0, odds = 0;
int negatives = 0, evens = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < numArray.size(); i++)
{
    cin >> numArray[i];

    // increment number of odds
    odds += numArray[i] & 0x1;
    // odds += numArray[i] % 2;

    // increment number of positives
    positives += (numArray[i] > 0);
    // positives += (numArray[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    // increment zeros
    zeros += !(numArray[i] | 0);
}

evens = 10 - odds;
negatives = 10 - zeros - positives;

cout << "Positive count " << positives << endl;
cout << "Negative Number " << negatives << endl;

cout << "Even number " << evens << endl;  
cout << "Odd number " << odds << endl;
```

and here is newbie friendly version:

```
int positives = 0, zeros = 0, odds = 0;
int negatives = 0, evens = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < numArray.size(); i++)
{
    cin >> numArray[i];

    // increment number of odds
    if (numArray[i] % 2 == 1)
        odds++;

    if (numArra[i] == 0)
        zeros++;
    else if (numArray[i] > 0)
        positives++;
}

evens = 10 - odds;
negatives = 10 - zeros - positives;

cout << "Positives " << positives << '\n';
cout << "Negatives " << negatives << '\n';

cout << "Evens " << evens << '\n';  
cout << "Odds " << odds << '\n';
```